# Getting columbia esterel compiler going

Tags: linux

I'm trying to set up the columbia esterel compiler on my Linux Mint 16 64 bit system.  [cec](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/cec/) . However, I'm not a very experienced Linux user, and I can't complete the task. The installing manual says, go to the esterel dir and type ./conifgure. But the terminal replies with "no permission". If I type make a few errors occur.

```
Making all in libantlr
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/thomas/Dokumente/cec-0.4/libantlr'
if g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"cec\" -DVERSION=\"0.4\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBEXPAT=1  -I. -I.     -g -O2 -MT CharScanner.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/CharScanner.Tpo" -c -o CharScanner.o `test -f 'src/CharScanner.cpp' || echo './'`src/CharScanner.cpp; \
then mv -f ".deps/CharScanner.Tpo" ".deps/CharScanner.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/CharScanner.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
In file included from src/CharScanner.cpp:18:0:
./antlr/CharScanner.hpp:416:30: error: ‘EOF’ was not declared in this scope
static const int EOF_CHAR = EOF;
                          ^
src/CharScanner.cpp: In member function ‘void antlr::CharScanner::panic()’:
src/CharScanner.cpp:93:8: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
exit(1);
     ^
src/CharScanner.cpp: In member function ‘void antlr::CharScanner::panic(const string&)’:
src/CharScanner.cpp:99:8: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
exit(1);
     ^
make[1]: *** [CharScanner.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/thomas/Dokumente/cec-0.4/libantlr'
make: *** [all-recursive] Fehler 1
```

I hope u can help me get this going. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the permissions for the file `configure` in the esterel directory? (That is, what does `ls -l configure` tell you?) They should start with either `rwx-` or `r-x-`, most likely the former.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem with the permission. The configure file was not executable. After that the configuration works without an error, but I still get the error message when I try to make the compiler. Anybody any suggestions for that problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve these issues (probably you'll get other problems like that during the compiling process) you have to open the file that generates the error and adding the appropriate library.

In particular, for your error: move to CharScanner.hpp directory (should be: cecdir/libantlr/antlr/CharScanner.hpp) and then add this include:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```